# Why do I get a horizontal scrollbar for width: 100% in chrome?

Tags: css

Starting with:

```
html, body 
{ 
    padding: 0; 
    width: 100%;
    font: 100%/1.45em "Lucida Grande", Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

Chrome decides that the width should be 1600px, which is wider than my current display, let alone the current Chrome window. I'm sure this is an old chestnut, but I'm failing to find the right tree.

I posted a complete example to git://github.com/bimargulies/css-mystery.git.

One note: My macbook was plugged into a very wide monitor, and is now not. The 1600px seems to me to be related to that, but I don't know how to make it go away except to reboot.

In the chrome devo tools, looking at the effective styles for the , I see:

```
width: 1600px;
   html, body - 100%
```

That 1600 is very mysterious. And this is after a reboot.

***EDIT*** bingo: buried in the style sheet main.css, from someone else I work 'with', was 'minWidth: 100em;' on body. oops.

Comment: No-repro in this fiddle in Chrome 10: http://jsfiddle.net/kjzBQ/ does the fiddle work for you, or break as well?

Comment: @Pekka: You have "normalized CSS" ticked.

Comment: @thirty ah, I see! Is that a new feature, or have I been overlooking it all the time? There was another case today where it distorted results.

Comment: @Pekka, I'm embarassed to admit that I don't know how to get jsFiddle to just show me the page.

Comment: @bmargulies neither do I :) But it's an iframe so the behaviour should be the same (there should be a scroll bar in the "result" pane)

Comment: @Pekka: You must have been overlooking it. It's been there for at least as long as I've been on SO (which is when I started using jsFiddle). http://jsfiddle.net/kjzBQ/1 without that pesky box ticked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the record, I think it's best to actually have the explanation in an answer.

There was another CSS clause way down the file:

```
body
{ 
    minWidth: 100em;
}
```

I didn't spot it, and the Chrome 'Computed Styles' box does not include this in the 'explanation' of the 1600px in the same way that it include `width` styles.

Answer (score 11):

You need to add `margin: 0` to remove the default `margin` on the `body` element.

Are you sure you need `width: 100%`?

`html` and `body` are by default "full width" due to being `block`-level elements.

Comment: Nope. The content is still width: 1600px according to the chrome developer tools, much wider than the available screen real estate. All that happened is that the left margin disappeared.

Comment: @bmargulies that sounds weird, it works perfectly for me if I apply @thirtydot's advice. Do you happen to have two screens? What is your screen's width? Are you 100% sure you have no element inside the page forcing it to stretch?

Comment: @bmargulies: http://fiddle.jshell.net/kjzBQ/2/show/light/ + Developer Tools shows me that both the `html` and `body` elements are as wide as my window: http://i.imgur.com/8ze0F.png - I think there's something else going on here :o

Comment: @thirty I agree, but the same silly thing happens in FF and in Chrome. I've posted the whole show to github, if you're feeling really kind to dumb animals you could take a look.

Comment: @bmargulies: Testing with a local version of [your page](https://github.com/bimargulies/css-mystery/blob/master/somethingwrong.html), and adding the CSS from your question, I can't reproduce with *any* of my browsers. I do have a horizontal scrollbar for the reason in my answer. Adding `margin: 0` or removing `width: 100%` fixes that. The fact that this seems related to plugging in different monitors, and that rebooting your computer fixes it leads me to believe it's not a HTML/CSS thing at all. It's some kind of operating system issue (???).

Comment: Is it only your page that has the obscure width? Does it still do it if you disable JavaScript?

Comment: Well, stackoverflow isn't having the problem :-) And I turn out not to know how to spike javascript in chrome. I guess I'll reboot and see what I see.

Comment: Hmm. I rebooted. And I still see the problem with the version of the page I put on github, which is self-contained, css-wise.

Comment: Disabling js has no effect, I found that.

Comment: Removing the width and letting it be width: auto; didn't change anything.

Comment: @bmargulies: Not such a crazy dilemma after all, was it? :D Oh well, I'm glad you figured it out.

Comment: Well, the wrong css was in the stuff I put on github. The stinky part of this is that chrome doesn't attribute the 1600px to the min width.

Comment: Ah, well that would explain it. I stupidly only copied your actual HTML file. I didn't touch the `somethingwrong_files` folder. Silly me!

Answer (score 3):

Try using a CSS reset...

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/index.html

... to set all CSS properties to their default values.

I hope this helps.
Hristo

Answer (score 2):

I had same issue. could be other div in body is having padding or margin.

Answer (score 0):

margin or padding can cause it.

in my case, was padding